# ¿Como hacer una consulta SQL de dos tablas con agrupamiento de la primera y join en la segunda?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como hago una consulta que me devuelva la minor fecha_alta de cada cod de la tabla1 y el nombre de la tabla 2

**1 - Tabla - movimiento** ................................**2 - Tabla - cuenta**

```
cod indicador   fecha_alta                  cod nombre
1   1/5 2018-10-01                           1  juan
1   2/5 2018-11-01                           2  marco
1   3/5 2018-12-01
2   1/3 2019-01-20
2   2/3 2019-02-20
2   2/3 2019-03-20
```

La consulta con agrupamiento debe retornar eso

```
cod nombre  indicador   fecha_alta
1   juan    1/5         2018-10-01
```

**3 - Tengo dos consultas distinctas** 
  a - la minor fecha

```
select distinct cod,min(fecha_alta)fecha_alta
from movimiento mov
group by cod
```

b - ejemplo sin agrupación

```
select 
c.cod,c.nombre,m.indicador,m.fecha_alta
from movimiento m
  inner join cuenta c(nolock) on m.cod = c.cod
where m.cod = 1
and m.indicador = '1/5'
```

Gracias de antemos por la ayuda .

Comment: ¿Cuál es el criterio o regla para indicar que el nombre de Juan esta relacionado con ese indicador y esa fecha_alta?

Comment: Aprendiz, el cod 1 (tabla cuenta)  y cod  1 (tabla movimiento) son los mismos. Elos se unem por el join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.cod,c.nombre,m.indicador,m.fecha_alta 
FROM movimiento m 
INNER JOIN cuenta c(nolock) on m.cod = c.cod 
WHERE m.cod = 1
AND m.indicador = '1/5' 
ORDER fecha_alta BY DESC
```

Creo que eso es lo que quieres !

Comment: Manuel, gracias pelo reporte. La consulta que he dejado es un ejemplo.
Tengo que traer la minor fecha de la tabla movimiento e depues los datos de la tabla cuenta. Mira que la tabla movimiento se repite los cod's e cambia los otros dos.

Comment: Podrías añadir una explicación del código? :)

Comment: Riaven, La tabla 2 tiene el cod 1 = juan. La tabla 1 tiene el cod 1 de juan. En la tabla 1 hay varios registros con varias fechas.
Necesito selecionar la minor fecha de la tabla 1 del cod 1 con lo respectivo indicador de la minor fecha. Añadir esos datos el nome de juan de quen lo cod es 1. Lo resultado debe ser lo que está arriba del item 3.